# How to search Woo Commerce products with punctuation in title?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search

How do I modify the default WooCommerce Product search so that products with punctuation in the title can be found without including the punctuation in the query?

For example, if I have a product titled "Map of Hawai‘i", I would like it to be the top result when someone searches for "Map of Hawaii".

Thanks